# How to strip an image from a paragraph, and then move it to the beginning of paragraph

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to figure out how to move an image in a small paragraph of text using regex, so that for example:

```
this is a <img src="image.jpg" /> paragraph
```

turns into

```
<img src="image.jpg" /> this is a paragraph
```

Does anyone have any ideas please

Comment: Is your paragraph in `<p>` tags?

Comment: no its not, it is just plain text with the image tag

Comment: Then how do you delimit the beginnings of new paragraphs?

Answer (score 5):

Simplified match, but will do for faux-XHTML:

```
 $src = preg_replace('/^(.*?)(<img[^>]+>)/m', '$2 $1', $src);
                       |   |    |                  |
           start of line   |    the img tag        switching
                         everything that follows   positions
```

This assumes you consider the start of a line the start of a paragraph.

Since this is your second regex question, I'd like to hint at reading http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php and http://regular-expressions.info/